# Using Sequelize with NodeJS and findByPk return pending

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Hello I try use Sequelize and I need return a Object in DB, this is a piece of my code;

Simple like that:

```
const { User, Appointment } = require('../models')
const moment = require('moment')
const { Op } = require('sequelize')

class MyAppointmentController {
  async index(req, res) {
    const { id } = req.session.user

    const appoitments = await Appointment.findAll({
      where: {
        providerId: id,
        date: {
          [Op.between]: [
            moment()
              .startOf('day')
              .format(),
            moment()
              .endOf('day')
              .format()
          ]
        }
      }
    })

    const available = appoitments.map(appoint => {
      const user = User.findByPk(appoint.userId).then(res => {
        console.log('Issue', res)
      })

      return {
        appoint,
        date: moment(appoint.date).format('HH:mm'),
        user: user.name,
        avatar: user.avatar
      }
    })

    return res.render('appointments/list', { available })
  }
}
module.exports = new MyAppointmentController()
```

I know this is a promise, but is impossible to get return...
The console res is print property

But ***user*** is always ***pending*** and if I try this

```
const user = User.findByPk(appoint.userId).then(res => {
            another_var = res
            return res
          })
```

console.log(enother_var) << undefined

Why does this happen? And How I can resolve this?

Comment: So you are trying to get the logged in user appointments and then modify how the date looks using `moment.js`, correct ?  
why not make use of Sequelize associations and associate the `Appointment` model to the `User` using `hasMany` so you can just then find the user's appointments easier using an `include` clause or a `getter` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop through a list but require an async call for each, I would recommend using `async/await`:

```
class MyAppointmentController {
  async index(req, res) {
    const { id } = req.session.user

    const appoitments = await Appointment.findAll({
      where: {
        providerId: id,
        date: {
          [Op.between]: [
            moment()
              .startOf('day')
              .format(),
            moment()
              .endOf('day')
              .format()
          ]
        }
      }
    })

    const available = [];

    for (appoint of appoitments) {
      const user = await User.findByPk(appoint.userId);

      available.push({
        appoint,
        date: moment(appoint.date).format('HH:mm'),
        user: user.name,
        avatar: user.avatar
      })
    };

    return res.render('appointments/list', { available })
  }
}
```

Here's why your code didn't work:

- You were calling `.map` on `appoitments` but never returning anything. You must return a value when calling `.map`. In your case, you presumably intended to return a list of user instances;
- In your loop, you assigned `user` to a promise, as opposed to the result of the promise. That is why it always read as `pending`.
- If you are calling an asyncronous method inside a loop, you must wait for that method to finish.

Comment: * my .map have a result... I just omitted in this post...  In My loop, I assigned user to a promise, as opposed to the result of the promise. That is why it always read as pending, So how get the result from a promisse ?

Comment: async and wait is required ? but other tutorial on web does have this keyword... Why in this case I need?

Comment: `async/await` is not required but it will make your code a lot cleaner. Assuming you can write ES6+, I would recommend it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really confuse about this... realy sorry... I Will post the whole code ok ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184481/discussion-between-mcranston18-and-jose-luiz).